# SharePoint PnP .. Set value for ModerationStatus

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I tried to set the "_ModerationStatus" in a SharePoint List with enabled content approval. I do it with SharePoint PnP (ClientSide).

I tried:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List $item.parentlist -Identity $item -Values @{"_ModerationStatus" = 0}
```

But nothing happens. I can change every fieldof the item. I tried several format of 0 or "0" or "Approved" or "Genehmigt" .. but without any effect.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You set a list items `_ModerationStatus` by accessing the list item property directly.

```
$item["_ModerationStatus"] = 0
$item.Update()
Execute-PnPQuery
```

I have tested this on a list with content approval enabled. Hopefully it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

Trying to update the `_ModerationStatus` property did not work for me.
I had to use the [Set-PnPFileCheckedIn](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPFileCheckedIn.html) cmdlet with the `-Approve` parameter.

> `Set-PnPFileCheckedIn -Url [ListItemURL] -Approve`